# trapping signal from "docker stop" in bash

Tags: bash, docker

i have an entry point script in a docker container that looks something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo starting up

function shut_down() {
    echo shutting down

    pid=$(ps -e | grep myapp | awk '{print $1}')
    kill -SIGTERM $pid  
    exit
}

trap "shut_down" SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGHUP SIGINT EXIT

/opt/myapp
```

I can't figure out how to trap the signal sent in by running `docker stop` on the container. When running interactively, a `ctrl+c` will trigger it as expected, but a `docker stop` command just waits for the 10 second timeout, and exits without ever entering the `shut_down` function

How can I trap the signal sent by `docker stop` in bash to do some cleanup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/lgierth/docker-exec/blob/master/docker-exec), could be inspiring :-)

**UPDATE:**

@nick-humrich here it is is my lamer copy & past (credit goes to the original author https://github.com/lgierth )

```
#!/bin/bash

function ensure_started_container {
  exists=`docker ps -q | grep $1`
  if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then
    echo "[docker-exec] skipping docker start, already started"
  else
    output=`docker start "$1"`
    echo "[docker start] $output"
  fi
  running=1
}

function setup_signals {
  cid="$1"; shift
  handler="$1"; shift
  for sig; do
    trap "$handler '$cid' '$sig'" "$sig"
  done
}

function handle_signal {
  echo "[docker-exec] received $2"
  case "$2" in
    SIGINT)
      output=`docker stop -t 5 "$1"`
      echo "[docker stop] $output"
      running=0
      ;;
    SIGTERM)
      output=`docker stop -t 5 "$1"`
      echo "[docker stop] $output"
      running=0
      ;;
    SIGHUP)
      output=`docker restart -t 5 "$1"`
      echo "[docker restart] $output"

      # restart logging
      docker attach "$1" &
      kill "$logger_pid" 2> /dev/null
      logger_pid="$!"
      ;;
  esac
}

running=0

setup_signals "$1" "handle_signal" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP

ensure_started_container "$1"

docker attach "$1" &
logger_pid="$!"

while true; do
  if [ "$running" = "1" ]; then
    sleep 1
  else
    break
  fi
done

exit_code=`docker wait "$1"`
exit "$exit_code"
```

Comment: specifically, `/opt/myapp` was running in the forground and preventing the trap from executing. The solution was to update that line to read like: `/opt/webapp & ; wait`

Comment: Reason for DV: Answers that are just links are considered poor answers. What happens if the link breaks?

Comment: @Nick-Humrich  WOW really !?!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Nick-Humrich yes, ... that's one of the reasons I almost stop using stackoverflow service at all, after more than 5 years membership, ... too much restrictions, authority, unuseful arbitrary moderation ( and so on :-)

Comment: Original link is a 404 now ;)

Comment: Link is now broken.

Answer (score 22):

Old question, but this will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo starting up

exec /opt/myapp
```

For details take a look here: https://akomljen.com/stopping-docker-containers-gracefully/

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm, and I've been scrambling all day to find an answer!

Comment: This should have been the answer! - But the link is now broken.

Comment: @XaviMontero I just reposted it on my new blog and edited the link. I will make a redirect to make old link working as well.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with xargs?

Answer (score 5):

Since Docker 1.9, you can use the `STOPSIGNAL` instruction in your `Dockerfile`:

> ```
> STOPSIGNAL signal
> ```
>
> The `STOPSIGNAL` sets the system call signal that will be sent to the container to
>   exit. This signal can be a valid unsigned number that matches a
>   position in the kernel’s syscall table, for instance 9, or a signal
>   name in the format SIGNAME, for instance SIGKILL.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#stopsignal

Comment: Note that, of all the signals you could use, signal 9 is probably the worst. It is called KILL because it kills the target process without giving it a chance to clean up. Using it on a poorly configured database server, for example, could be catastrophic.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, simply setting a trap didn't work. I had to set the process to background to catch the signal, otherwise the signal went to the started process itself.

the original last line of the starting script was:

```
sudo -H -u "$uid" sh -c "myserviced"
```

I replaced this line with the following code:

```
shutdown_myservice() {
  set +e
  echo "[SHUTDOWN] Shutting down myservice"
  sudo -u "$uid" myservicecmd -c Shutdown
  echo "[SHUTDOWN] sent. $?"
  wait $dpid  # make sure the process terminated and not just started stopping
  echo "[SHUTDOWN] down. $?"
  return 0
}

trap "shutdown_myservice" HUP INT QUIT TERM USR1

# here, start the process in BACKGROUND
sudo -H -u "$uid" sh -c "myserviced" &
dpid=$!
wait $dpid
```

This way, the "focus" wasn't on the daemon anymore. instead, it was on the start script. I seems that only the "focus" process (foreground process) gets the signal.