# How to stop docker container automatically?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am trying to stop the docker container automatically after 1 hour. I mean, if there is no process going on or the container is idle for 1 hour, then stop that container. Is this possible to do it programmatically within the Dockfile? Any thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this > https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651986/1535270

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest solution that fits your problem supported by `Dockerfile` would be [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) directive e.g. `HEALTHCHECK [OPTIONS] CMD command` . Here you can specify interval (e.g. 1 hour) and time out.

```
--interval=DURATION (default: 30s)
--timeout=DURATION (default: 30s)
--start-period=DURATION (default: 0s)
--retries=N (default: 3)
```

Other than that you would have to create `custom shell script` that is triggered by `cronjob` every 1 hour. In this script you would stop foreground process and by that stooping the running container.

Comment: Actually , I am using NGINX as reverse proxy. The condition is, if there is no incoming http request in last 1 hour then I need to stop that container.

Comment: You could do it by parsing the access log of nginx. Each request has timestamp (or date and time) that you could easily scrap for.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference doc or link?

Comment: Check this tutorial on [NGINX Access Logs](https://www.journaldev.com/26756/nginx-access-logs-error-logs) Beside that I'd recommend to write simple python script to extract date/timestamp from access.log and combined it with [cronjob](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) or [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck). That would be my strategy.

Comment: Thanks, @Lukasz Dynowski. The HEALTHCHECK is working. But, we choose another way by running another pod to monitoring the Prometheus metrics.

Comment: @JDGuide sounds like you did side car deployment -very clever!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know such a scenario is not part of the docker workflow.

The container is alive a long as its main process is alive. When that project (PID: 1) exits (with error or success) then the container also stops.

So the only way I see is to either build this logic inside your program (the main process in the container) or wrap the program in a shell script that kills the process based on some rule (like no log entries for a certain amount of time).